# future.get returning before finally executed in Callable on cancel

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I'm have a test that is failing intermittently where a future.get call is returning before the finally block is executed in the Callable, when the future is canceled.  Here's the basic workflow:

`future.cancel(true);`

I see the `InterrupedException` thrown in the `Callable`

The main thread catches `CancellationException` from the `future.get` call

Now the `Callable` calls `finally`.

The test is always successful on my notebook and fails most of the time on our build server.  Both my notebook and the build server are running OpenJDK 1.7.  Any ideas?

Comment: can u post the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `cancel()` doesn't seem to specify that it waits for the interrupted thread to exit. If you want that guarantee, you'll have to set up a monitor or some other synchronization mechanism whereby the canceler can wait for the processor to say "I'm done with my finally-block".

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it's a bug since that behavior is not documented